# Highlight Rows That Match Based On Certain Cells

Tags: excel

Please excuse me if I am expecting too much here but I was thinking there must be a quicker way than the way I've been doing it.

So I have spreadsheets that I have to sort and match rows based on criteria in certain columns (in this example, columns `F`, `G`, `H`, `I`, `J`, and `K` are compared) and highlight matching rows a color so its different from the other rows and continue this until every row is colored. Below is an image of the start data and the ideal end of what I need.

My problem comes from not knowing how to tell it to look and compare the appropriate columns. I can get it to work if I tell it to only look at one column. For example I can get it to work if all I look at were column `J` but as you can see in the pictures, Column `J` can have different variables in the other columns that would cause it to be colored differently. I was hoping someone here might know an easier way of doing this as I've been struggling with this for a couple days and seem to be getting no where fast.

Here is the code I have found online that can change a row based on one variable. With this code, it sees the RRR in column `J` and highlights all rows that have RRR even though they match in the other columns.

```
Sub ChangeColor()
lRow = Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set MR = Range("F2:K" & lRow)
For Each cell In MR
If cell.Value Like "*RRR*" Then cell.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 20


    Next
End Sub
```

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/l6hgB.jpg)
[image: Screentshot]

EDIT!
So I have been able to piece together a working code based on some feed back and ideas here. This isn't the prettiest but user Byron has an amazingly shorter and quicker code that I might tinker with to get what I need.

```
Sub Highlight_Duplicate_Entry()

Range("AA2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=CONCATENATE(RC[-13],RC[-12],RC[-11],RC[-10],RC[-9],RC[-8])"
Range("AA2").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("AA2:AA279"), Type:=xlFillDefault
Range("AA2:AA400").Select


Dim cel As Variant
Dim myrng As Range
Dim clr As Long
Set myrng = Range("AA2:AA" & Range("AA65536").End(xlUp).Row)
myrng.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
clr = 36
For Each cel In myrng
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(myrng, cel) > 1 Then
        If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("AA2:AA" & cel.Row), cel) = 1 Then
            cel.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = clr
            clr = clr + 1
        Else
            cel.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex =      myrng.Cells(WorksheetFunction.Match(cel.Value, myrng, False),        1).Interior.ColorIndex
        End If
    End If
Next

lRow = Range("AA" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
 Set MR = Range("AA2:AA" & lRow)
 For Each cell In MR
 If cell.Value Like "*SMLS*" Then cell.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 20


Next
    Columns("AA:AA").Select
Selection.ClearContents
Range("K2").Select

 End Sub
```

Comment: add a new column that concatenates all the values together that you must check in a new column then use that as your single column.

Comment: xQbert thats a good idea! Now i need to try and figure out how to compare the results and highlight duplicates different colors. Great idea

Comment: The new column is not necessary imo

Comment: chancea - Just like VBA, my work with conditional formatting is very limited. This sounds like something that could be easily achieved with conditional formatting?

Comment: Well maybe not 'easy', ill play around a bit.

Comment: I really appreciate it. I will start to look into it as well, honestly never crossed my mind to use conditional formatting.

Comment: Since in Conditional Formatting you [cannot color the whole row with Graded Color Scale](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10394591/excel-conditional-formatting-3-color-over-one-row-applied-to-many-rows) my idea is out the window :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Detecting ranges of data that are the same is fairly easy to do.  The standard way is to use the method of @xQbert which is to concatenate values together.  In VBA this is easy because there is a `Join` Function which will take an array and turn it into a string.  This is harder (or really more tedious) in Excel formulas because `CONCATENATE` requires every item separately.

Using `Join` you can create an "ID" for the row which is just all of the cells joined together.  If you combine this with a `Dictionary`, you can store the desired row colors in there and then apply that color to the row.

The only hard part here is deciding which colors you want to use.  I am currently just making random numbers which generally makes something that is usable.  You could extend this to use a list of colors if you know how many total colors that are needed.

**Code** requires that you add a reference (`Tools->References`) to the `Microsoft Scripting Runtime` in order for the `Dictionary` to work.

```
Sub ColorForUnique()

    'must add a reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime
    Dim dict As New Scripting.Dictionary

    'build range from block of data
    'only check columns F:K for matches
    Dim rng_match As Range
    Set rng_match = Intersect( _
        Range("B2:M8"), _
        Range("F:K"))

    Dim rng_row As Range
    For Each rng_row In rng_match.Rows

        Dim id As String
        id = Join(Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(rng_row.Value)), "")

        If Not dict.Exists(id) Then
            dict.Add id, RGB(Application.RandBetween(0, 255), Application.RandBetween(0, 255), Application.RandBetween(0, 255))
        End If

        rng_row.EntireRow.Interior.Color = dict(id)
    Next rng_row
End Sub
```

**Limits/notes on code**

- I am using the double `Transpose` to force the `.Value` to be a 1D array of values.  This and the use of `.Rows` for the loop means this only works for a contiguous block of data.  You could build a different loop if all your columns are not together.

**Picture of results** for some arbitrary data shows the desired coloring.  I use your columns so that you should be able to just run this code.

*Before*

[image: before]

*After*

[image: after]

**Edit to allow color selection**: this code can be easily extended to allow for color selection instead of random coloring.  The `Dictionary` provides a nice built in counter for how many IDs are in play using `Dictionary.Count`.  You can use that as an index for choosing a color.  You could also just use the integer as the color to use although those colors are not that ideal.

Modify the color adding step to use a function instead of just random numbers:

```
If Not dict.Exists(id) Then
    dict.Add id, GetColor(dict.Count + 1)
End If
```

And then define the `GetColor` Function to provide whatever colors are desired.  You could also fill this with `ColorIndex` values if you prefer those.  Change color using `Interior.ColorIndex` later if you do that.  Here are two options for that Function.  One does random colors, the other returns colors from the ColorBrewer pallette.

```
'random colors always
Function GetColor(index As Integer) As Long

    GetColor = RGB(Application.RandBetween(0, 255), _
        Application.RandBetween(0, 255), Application.RandBetween(0, 255))

End Function

'first 10 colors from the ColorBrewer palette
Function GetColor(index As Integer) As Long

    Dim colors(1 To 10) As Long

    colors(6) = RGB(166, 206, 227)
    colors(1) = RGB(31, 120, 180)
    colors(7) = RGB(178, 223, 138)
    colors(3) = RGB(51, 160, 44)
    colors(8) = RGB(251, 154, 153)
    colors(2) = RGB(227, 26, 28)
    colors(9) = RGB(253, 191, 111)
    colors(4) = RGB(255, 127, 0)
    colors(10) = RGB(202, 178, 214)
    colors(5) = RGB(106, 61, 154)

    'protect against bad index
    If index > UBound(colors) Or index < LBound(colors) Then
        GetColor = RGB(255, 255, 255)
    Else
        GetColor = colors(index)
    End If

End Function
```

Comment: This is amazing! Especially for how short the code it. I was actually able to Frankenstein together my own code that seems to work well except that it doesnt give not duplicate rows their own color. Would it be easy to change how the colors are selected on yours? In mine it references the color index (I added the code as an answer and would love your feedback)

Comment: See edit for some thoughts on color selection.  I keep the `GetColor` Function in my general toolkit for times like this.  It gives 10 good colors to start.  Mostly useful for styling charts.

Comment: Sorry for the stupid question but do I just add the GetColor function into the original Sub code or into its own module? I dont think I have ever done anything with Functions before. :(

Comment: Same module is fine.  Before or after the `Sub` doesn't matter.  Just make sure it is outside the boundaries of `Sub ... End Sub`

Comment: You sir, are amazing! This works great and I cant wait to get the rest of my macro finished so I can add this to it. I cant explain how much time you just saved me. Now I just need to add some more colors. Thanks again!